# AssertionError when using uwsgi with pypy with the sample test app

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm trying to get the sample pypy test hello world application to run using uwsgi with pypy.  I've attempted to build uwsgi with the pypy plugin (using `python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/pypy`) and pypy in my home directory.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PyPy.html

However, when I use the command

```
 ~/uwsgi-2.0.4/uwsgi --plugin ~/uwsgi-2.0.4/pypy --http-socket :9090 --pypy-home ~/pypy-2.2.1-linux64/ --pypy-wsgi uwsgi_pypy_test.wsgi --pypy-lib ~/uwsgi-2.0.4/plugins/pypy/libpypy-c-x86_64_20130524.so
```

it exits with a `OperationalError` and `AssertionError`:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.4 (64bit) on [Wed May  7 11:14:46 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 01 May 2014 10:11:39
os: Linux-3.8.0-35-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:24:40 UTC 2014
nodename: mcp03
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /var/www/pypytest/src
detected binary path: /home/alphad/uwsgi-2.0.4/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 128233
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :9090 fd 3
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: AssertionError
debug:  operror-value:
```

*uwsgi_pypy_test.wsgi*

```
def application(e, sr):
    sr('200 Ok', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return "ciao"
```

Has anyone gotten pypy to run succesfully with uwsgi?  I'm trying the most basic configuration here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the exact same issue (same errors).  I'm running this in Docker, but I don't *think* that's involved.  I'm using uWSGI 2.0.12, and pypy 2.4.0.

Comment: No, I don't think I ever got this working.  I believe I settled with standard python +uwsgi + nginx